# jquery how to make checkbox always checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, checkbox, struts

**How can I make a checkbox always be checked, with Jquery 1.4.2 ?**

*This is my html output from the struts application:*

```
<input type="checkbox" name="helloThere" value="on">
```

I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#helloThere').attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

**JSFIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/96p4zg9w/ this shows the current code, I would need the checkbox to load checked.

The [props property is not available](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) in JQUERY 1.4.2

Comment: I think you need .prop

Comment: prop is for jquery 1.6 and above and this being a legacy application is actually using jquery1-4-2 :/

Comment: For us to help you, you would have to give us the HTML equivalent of `<html:checkbox property="helloThere'">helloThere'</html:checkbox>` ... we don't process jsp, but you server is doing that already for your browser :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your jquery selector is wrong.

You are trying select an element with 'helloThere' id, but your input has not an id attribute.
You can add this attribute to your input field or change jquery selector.

Try one of this tow solutions:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="helloThere" id="helloThere" value="on">
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name='helloThere']").attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

Comment: in your JSFIDDLE you should load the jquery library.

Comment: thanks! I ended up having to search by attribute since I cant add id.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your JavaScript inside [`$(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). This ensures all of the content you might want to touch has been loaded before you try to change it.

In your scenario then, you would need:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#helloThere').attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

**Edit**: Your checkbox doesn't have an ID. You need to add an ID of "helloThere" for `$('#helloThere')` to pick it up. Your fiddle also needs to have jQuery loaded using the menu on the left. Here's a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/96p4zg9w/1/

Comment: it is in a document ready and it still not setting to checked, check my jsfiddle

Comment: Updated answer with working fiddle :) Alternatively, if you can't use an ID for whatever reason, you can use a name attribute selector: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/96p4zg9w/2/)

Comment: I voted up your answer thanks, but I cant add id value to html since its generated by struts. And struts I cant add ids and stuff to html tags, but I used what previous answer suggested and looked up by attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/69e9sob6/) for a working example of how you can do it using javascript.
If you want to use versions of jQuery below 1.5, you need to do it this way:

```
$("#checkbox").attr("checked", true);
```

or

```
$("#checkbox").attr("checked", "checked");
```

If you want to select element using the name instead of id, use:

```
input[name='helloThere']
```

Hope it useful!

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in three ways. You can use checked in input that will always stay checked.

```
<input id="myId" type="checkbox" name="name" checked>
```

Using prop and assume input id is myId

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $(#myId).prop('checked', true);
 });
```

Before jQuery 1.6 using attr

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $(#ID).attr('checked','checked');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
   <lable>this will always be checked, even you try to uncheck</lable>:
   <input type="checkbox" checked onclick="return false;">
```